# Biometric authentication and oauth2 in an app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, oauth-2.0, biometrics

My flutter app currently uses OAuth to authenticate users.  I am using the Resource Owner Password grant.  I want to add biometric authentication to the app (finger/face id).

What is the approach when adding biometric authentication to an app which still needs to do OAuth in the background?  Do I store the UID and PWD in a secure location and use it int he background to authenticate against OAuth?  What is the most secure pattern for this scenario?

Comment: Hi Igor, did you find a solution for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

you usually store a session token returned from the OAuth system that you check every so often for expiry, you don't save the User/Password with OAuth systems